# Is there a way to embed an audio file in Microsoft Word so it plays inside Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, audio

I have an old version of Word but I was thinking of getting a **new** version if it could embed an audio file because I've been writing a lot of documents on music theory and composition.

But my GF has the latest Word version for 2022 and I STILL can't find a way to do this.

**I want the equivalent of embedding a picture** -  it appears in the text and you see it **inside** your document.  You don't have to click on the picture name and view it in a separate viewer window.   I want the same thing with an MP3 file - I want the reader to click on some icon or text in the document and have the sound come out of their speakers without opening Windows Media Player or whatever their default audio player is.

HTML can do this -  there's web pages all over the place that do it -  how do I do it in a recent version of Word?

Answer (score 1):

### Word cannot do this. PowerPoint can.

To me, the amazing thing is that you can even insert the audio file in a Word document at all. Word is designed to put words on paper; that is its core purpose.

Comment: It seems weird that in 2022, when we live in a deeply multimedia world, that a major product like Word is so limited.   Granted, it's called "Word", but you can embed pictures.  These files are for distribution to my students - is there some other document-type that allows lots of formatted text and is easy to create and edit with, like Word is, that's more multimedia-friendly?  PowerPoint isn't really good for creating lots of paragraphs of text.

Comment: Word's core purpose is to put words (and now pictures) on paper. Sounds do not work for that, neither do videos. PowerPoint is designed to present multimedia. It is not as good at text editing. You can create a PP deck based on a Word document using heading styles. Note, this forum is not about making changes or improvements to software but is about how to use what is. For changes, contact Microsoft using their feedback mechanisms. https://support.microsoft.com/office/2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11